# Is the Geometric distribution sub-exponential?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Simply put, if $X \sim Geom(p)$, such that

$P(X=x) = (1-p)^x p$

does $X$ have sub-exponential tails?

Edit: **Definition 1: Sub-exponential random variable** $X$ is subexponential with parameters $(\sigma^2, b)$ if for all $|\lambda| < 1/b$, its centered moment-generating function $M_{X-E(X)}$ satisfies,

$log(M_{X-E(x)}(\lambda)) \leq \frac{\lambda^2\sigma^2}{2}$

Comment: What is the definition of "subexponential"?

Comment: added the defintion now

Comment: What have you tried? Did you compute the centered moment-generating function?

Answer (score 0):

We compute the first moment of $X$ by
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k(1-p)^kp = \frac{1-p}p
$$
and similarly
$$
\mathbb E[X^2] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2p(1-p)^k = \frac{(2-p) (1-p)}{p^2},
$$
hence
$$
\sigma^2 = \mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2 = \frac{(2-p) (1-p)}{p^2} - \left(\frac{1-p}p\right)^2 = \frac{1-p}{p^2}.
$$
Now, $$M_{X-\mathbb E[X]}(\lambda) = \mathbb E[e^{\lambda(X-\mathbb E[X])}]=e^{-\frac{\lambda(1-p)}p}\mathbb E[e^{\lambda X}]$$
and
$$
\mathbb E[e^{\lambda X}] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{\lambda k}(1-p)^kp = \frac p{1-e^\lambda(1-p)},
$$
hence
$$M_{X-\mathbb E[X]}(\lambda) = e^{-\frac{\lambda(1-p)}p}\cdot\frac p{1-e^\lambda(1-p)}.$$
Now we take the log of $M_{X-\mathbb E[X]}(\lambda)$ and need to bound it by
$$
\frac{\lambda^2\sigma^2}2 = \frac{\lambda^2(1-p)}{2p^2}.
$$
Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I found getting to this part easier than finding a good $b$ so that $|{\lambda}| \leq 1/b$ implies the inequality holds. Any advice? Ideally I'd just look this up on some table somewhere, maybe you know of such table.